# Apache Camel Intercept - Capture Output.

Tags: apache-camel, interceptor

I am attempting to use Apache Camel Interceptor in the spring.xml file to capture incoming requests and outgoing responses, like this:

```
    <bean id="InterceptProcessor" class="CaptureProcessor"/>
<camel:camelContext id="camel">
    <camel:jmxAgent id="agent" disabled="true" />
    <camel:intercept>
        <camel:process ref="InterceptProcessor"></camel:process>
    </camel:intercept>
    <camel:route id="Resource.rConnect.rconnect" autoStartup="false">
        <camel:from
            uri="cxfjetty:${Resource.rConnect.rconnect.baseUrl}?urlTemplateRef=#URLTemplateRef.Resource.rConnect.rconnect&amp;
            convertAttachments=true" />
        <camel:to
            uri="sonicesb://Process/rConnect?bindingStrategy=#ExposeBindingStrategy.Resource.rConnect.rconnect&amp;headerFilterStrategy=#ExposeHeaderFilterStrategy.Resource.rConnect.rconnect&amp;esbConfig=#ExposeEsbConfig.Resource.rConnect.rconnect" />
    </camel:route>
    <camel:route autoStartup="false">
        <camel:from
            uri="directsonicesb:Resource.rConnect.rconnect?bindingStrategy=#InvokeBindingStrategy.Resource.rConnect.rconnect&amp;headerFilterStrategy=#InvokeHeaderFilterStrategy.Resource.rConnect.rconnect&amp;uriTemplate=#URITemplate.Resource.rConnect.rconnect" />
        <camel:to uri="sonicesb://Process/rConnect" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Following [this](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html) article.

But the "CaptureProcessor" is only called once on the input cycle.

How can I make it capture the Output as well?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Camel doc](https://camel.apache.org/intercept.html), this is not possible with `intercept`:

> What happens is that the Exchange is intercepted before each processing step, that means that it will be intercepted before

Thus, it is not possible to intercept the processing **after** each step. However, there's an open Jira ticket for this requirement: [CAMEL-6901](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6901)

Alternatively, you may use `onCompletion` that is like an after completion callback which can be defined for each route or globally for the whole Camel context:

```
<onCompletion>
    <log message="${body}" />
</onCompletion>
```

See the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html) for more information about this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

I found an approach that suited me better.

Using the intercept in my original question, then in the process class: Use a Synchronization and add the onCompletion processor.

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
public class CaptureProcessor implements Processor, Synchronization    
{
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exch) throws Exception
    {
         if (exch.hasOut())
         {
           // you won't get here
         } else
         {
            // ==== Add the onCompletion interceptor ====
            exch.addOnCompletion(this);
            // do in processing
                      ....
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Exchange exch)
    {
         if (exch.hasOut())
         {
                  // do the out procesing
                          ....
        } else
        {
             // you won't get here  
              }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exchange exch)
    {
            // you get the idea by now
    }
}
```

And the inbound and outbound intercept are only called once each.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Peter.

That did the trick.

Some interesting outcomes though

- The intercept entry is still required to capture the incoming request.
- Once I added the onCompletion entry to my Spring configuration, the Processor is invoked four times, three in and one out.

I tried moving the intercept and onCompletion entries into dofferent places but always got the same result. My solution was to add a specific Header on the first inbound call and bypass processing on the others if the header was already there.

Regards
Steve