# org.apache.camel.Processor get source ip address

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have a camelContext interceptor that calls a Processor like this. You can see my spring.xml [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555899/apache-camel-intercept-capture-output/23667223#23667223).

```
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class CaptureProcessor implements Processor
{
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exch) throws Exception
    {
            ....
    }
```

Is it possible to find the Client's Source IP address in the Exchange object?

Note that this article that finds the IP addrerss by extracting the Message body as an [HttpServerletRequest](https://github.com/tmielke/fuse-demos/blob/master/Camel/Camel-Jetty-Client-IP/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/test/SimpleProcessor.java) is not applicable because mine is a simple REST service and does not implement a serverlet. My input Message body is a String.

Answer (score 0):

The Camel exchange contains the http headers from the request. Best would be to dump the headers to the log to find out what is available with your particular setup of proxies, web servers, etc. There are several header fields that may or may not exist that contain the client's IP: `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Client-IP`, `X-Real-IP`, etc.

You can log the headers like so:

```
<camel:to uri="log:dump.headers?level=DEBUG&amp;showHeaders=true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Ralf. I tried adding the line bud didn't see anything in the container log. I had already looked in the Exchange Properties and Message Headers in the Processor but didn't see anything there. Would I expect to see anything different by dumping the headers?

Comment: No, the result would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the **ip** in exchange header's with property  `X-forwarded-for` :

`String ip=exchange.getIn().getHeader("X-forwarded-for");`